Width range for commuter/hybrid/road style tires for a 40mm rim width?
I have a Santa Cruz hard tail mountain bike with 27.5 tires on a 40mm rim and I want to put smooth commuter style tires on it. I have looked at various charts and done some searching but I'm having a hard time figuring out which tires would work for this type of setup. Would I follow the general mountain bike guidelines and go with 2.4-3.0 width? I have also heard you can get away with significantly more narrow road-style tires and I was hoping to get something like 2.0s (or even slightly narrower), but not sure if that would be an issue.
Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

This sounds like a 27.5+ bike. If you're willing to spend a few hundred USD, you might consider buying a 29" wheelset with a relatively narrow width (25mm), which would enable you to run common 700c road and commuter tires (28mm, 32mm, etc).

Get a Schwalbe Land Cruiser set. Bring the bike to the purchase and the staff will tell You if they will fit for free. Happy riding!

40 mm rims (if really the inner width) are really wide. Forget any narrow tyres. According to the ETRTO specifications you need at least 66 mm wide tyres. That is 2.6". 2.0 should be a clear no-go. 2.4 at your risk.
If the inner width is actually narrower than 40 mm, consult the recommended rim compatibility of any tyre you consider buying. The vendor may relax the ETRTO recommendations in some way.

Here is a public source for the current ETRTO recommendations, I think finalized in 2021 or 22.

Consider purchasing a second set of wheels. The new wheels will be lighter and allow use of narrower tires. A wheelset can be $100-$150 on ebay.
If you stick with the original wheels consider the 42mm or 50mm version of Continental Contact Urban tires. They are relatively light, roll easily, and have decent puncture protection.
